# httpcilent PostAsJsonAsync return null in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, controller, httpclient

I am using an HTTP endpoint  `HttpClient`  to send request to my controller like that:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:5075/Agent/ChangeAgent");
 
            var model = new ChangeAgentRequestViewModel
            {
                Address = "test",
                AgentType = 1,

            };
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync (uri, model);
```

So in my controller I get model:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeAgent(ChangeAgentRequestViewModel model)
        {

            var res = await _agentService.SaveAgent(model);
            return Json(res);
        }
```

I expect this model contain `AgentType or Address` but value for both is `0 and null`. When I am changing my request input as [FromBody] it is going to work, but because it is call by another endpoint I don't want to change my controller like  `public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeAgent([FromBody]ChangeAgentRequestViewModel model)` . so is there any method that give me that values in `httpclient` ?

Comment: What does the JSON being posted look like? The client might be using camel case and the server expecting Pascal Case, or visa versa.  If that’s the problem, the most straightforward fix might be to specify the JSON names by setting the JsonPropertyName Attribute on the properties in the class, so they are the same on each side. See: https://makolyte.com/csharp-deserialize-json-using-different-property-names/

Comment: Why don’t you want to use FromBody attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need know that `PostAsJsonAsync` sends a POST request to the specified Uri **containing the value serialized as JSON in the request body**.

Then `[FromBody]` means the api requires `application/json` content type data, but you said if you do not specify the source by `[FromBody]`, it will not receive value. That is to say the request api need data posted from form.

So if you do not want to specify the `[FromBody]` attribute, you need send data like below:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Address", "test"},
    {"AgentType", "1"}
};

var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new FormUrlEncodedContent(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all about model binding, you can find more information here [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#binding-source-parameter-inference)

Use the `[ApiController]` attribute for your controller. If you don’t want to add this attribute to all controllers but you have a class that all other controllers inherit from, then you can add it to that class since this attribute is inherited.